# Keyboard and shifted modals in iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard

I am having issues with iPad, keyboards and modals in `formSheet` (or `pageSheet` since iOS 13).

I am developing a chat, and I have an input bar that I want to be moved above the keyboard when it appears, like WhatsApp and similar.

This is a simplified version of my code, called after receiving `UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification`, being `keyboardFrame` the end frame of the keyboard:

```swift
    func keyboardDidShow(withFrame keyboardFrame: CGRect, notification: Notification) {
        let viewFrame: CGRect
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            viewFrame = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame
        } else {
            viewFrame = view.frame
        }

        let convertedKeyboardFrame = view.convert(keyboardFrame, from: nil)
        let intersection = viewFrame.intersection(convertedKeyboardFrame)

        updateBottomConstraint( // The bottom constraint of the input bar
            constant: -intersection.height,
            animationDuration: notification.keyboardAnimationDuration
        )
    }
```

It is working for every screen size, version and device but iPad with `formSheet` or `pageSheet` presentations there is a blank space between the bottom of my input bar and the top of the keyboard.

[image: bug]

In this situation, my view controller is shifted up a bit to give room to the keyboard, ruining my code.

I don't want to calculate things or to know about the window or superview, I would like to rely on layout guides or whatever in the scope of my view controller. I am not able to find any information related with this, and I assume this is not so strange.

Any idea?